# D: Templated structure : not initializing

Tags: d

I am trying to learn D (Googling for this language is impossible, btw. tips on that?), and am stuck with this problem.

Consider:

```
// Bitfield utilities
struct RegBit(int bitnumber, int nbits, T) {
    T data;
    uint mask = 46;
    ubyte r = 3;
}

struct cpu_t {

// registers
union {
    ushort AF = 56;
    struct {
        ubyte F;
        ubyte A;
    };
    // flags
    RegBit!(7, 1, ushort) fZ;
    RegBit!(6, 1, ushort) fN;
    RegBit!(5, 1, ushort) fH;
    RegBit!(4, 1, ushort) fC;
};
```

then running this,

```
writefln ("%d", CPU.fC.data);
writefln ("%d", CPU.fC.r);
```

begets the output

```
56
0
```

my question is: why?

Comment: When searching, it might help to add the terms "dlang" or use the full "D programming language" three word name. Also feel free to pop in here or to the chat channel #d on freenode irc and ask us in there if searching doesn't turn anything up.

Comment: Simply go to the official D web-site - http://www.dlang.org . There you will find the language reference, the phobos documentation, and finally, you will find a link to the D wiki - http://wiki.dlang.org . This is more than enough to learn D. I know because I learned D just by reading the language reference part of the D web-site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the only field of the union that gets initialized is `AF` and this happens to coincide with the data field of the RegBit structs. All the rest just gets ignored during standard initialization so the `r` fields of the `RegBit`s never get touched (and would all be the same anyway)

the true issue is the use of the union, honestly you shouldn't need it in most cases

Comment: thanks, this is a tricky divergence from C++ then. I would then need a constructor inside the struct.

the union will allow me to twiddle bits, i am not sure how i could do that without it.

something like fC = 1; will set whatever bit to 1 using an overloaded '='

Comment: may I suggest using a [BitField](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html) instead